# Saving a URL in a bash variable causes curl to fail

Tags: linux, bash, curl

In a bash script I've stored the URL from a previous command in a bash variable `$DESTINATION_URL`. I want to run a curl command using this variable.

If I use the `$DESTINATION_URL` variable, the curl command fails.

If I try that same curl command with the URL itself, it works fine. It seems like the `&` is causing a problem, but I can't see why.

Example below:

```
ha@hadoop-fullslot1:~$ echo $DESTINATION_URL
http://hadoop-fullslot1:50075/webhdfs/v1/user/ha/s3distcp.jar?op=CREATE&user.name=hdfs&namenoderpcaddress=hadoop-meta1:8020&overwrite=true


ha@hadoop-fullslot1:~$ curl -v -s -i -X PUT -T $SOURCE "$DESTINATION_URL"
* About to connect() to hadoop-fullslot1 port 50075 (#0)
*   Trying 10.1.3.39... connected
 HTTP/1.1bhdfs/v1/user/ha/s3distcp.jar?op=CREATE&user.name=hdfs&namenoderpcaddress=hadoop-meta1:8020&overwrite=true
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: hadoop-fullslot1:50075
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 1907377
> Expect: 100-continue
>
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host hadoop-fullslot1 left intact
* Closing connection #0


ha@hadoop-fullslot1:~$ curl -v -s -i -X PUT -T $SOURCE "http://hadoop-fullslot1:50075/webhdfs/v1/user/ha/s3distcp.jar?op=CREATE&user.name=hdfs&namenoderpcaddress=hadoop-meta1:8020&overwrite=true"
* About to connect() to hadoop-fullslot1 port 50075 (#0)
*   Trying 10.1.3.39... connected
> PUT /webhdfs/v1/user/ha/s3distcp.jar?op=CREATE&user.name=hdfs&namenoderpcaddress=hadoop-meta1:8020&overwrite=true HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: hadoop-fullslot1:50075
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 1907377
> Expect: 100-continue
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< Cache-Control: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
< Expires: Fri, 26 Apr 2013 09:01:38 GMT
Expires: Fri, 26 Apr 2013 09:01:38 GMT
< Date: Fri, 26 Apr 2013 09:01:38 GMT
Date: Fri, 26 Apr 2013 09:01:38 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: Fri, 26 Apr 2013 09:01:38 GMT
Expires: Fri, 26 Apr 2013 09:01:38 GMT
< Date: Fri, 26 Apr 2013 09:01:38 GMT
Date: Fri, 26 Apr 2013 09:01:38 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
< Location: webhdfs://hadoop-meta1:50070/user/ha/s3distcp.jar
Location: webhdfs://hadoop-meta1:50070/user/ha/s3distcp.jar
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Length: 0
Content-Length: 0
< Server: Jetty(6.1.26.cloudera.2)
Server: Jetty(6.1.26.cloudera.2)

<
* Connection #0 to host hadoop-fullslot1 left intact
* Closing connection #0
ha@hadoop-fullslot1:~$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable contains something more (garbage) than just the URL. I would guess on a CR byte or something, see how " HTTP/1.1" gets printed first on the line although it should be on the right of the URL...

Comment: to check whether this is the case, try something like `echo "|${DESTINATION_URL}|" so you see any whitespace.

Comment: There are no special character in the URL because the CURL command works fine if I put it directly to the command (instead of using variable).

Comment: We get "HTTP/1.1 100 Continue" because we try to send out data before the redirect. - [See more](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#CREATE)

Comment: You're missing the point. Look at the debug log in the failing case and how it shows the URL it used. Compare to the working case. Figure out the difference!

Comment: Examine the exact contents of the variable: `printf "%s" "$DESTINATION_URL" | od -c`

Comment: You're right. The variable contains _carriage return character_ `\r` at the end so that the CURL command failed. I fixed it by remove the last character: `${DESTINATION_URL:0:-1}`. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

use single quote `'` instead of double quote `"`

Comment: I have to use double quote because I want to pass a variable as parameter to the CURL command.